# error in estimate distance?

Tags: gps, distance, latitude-longitude

i do some experiment place two sensor node between them 4 meter as distance.

then i get these GPS information:

node1:  `Latitude: 32, 33.255  , Longitude: 36, 0.6632`

node2:  `Latitude: 32, 33.228  , Longitude: 36, 0.6588`

then to try to find the distance between them i use this [Link](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html), but i surprised that the distance calculated is 50 meters !!!!!

how can i go over this problem !

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you may want to check if the coordinates for your nodes are correct, because I just plotted them in Google Earth and they are 50 m apart. It may also be a problem with the accuracy of the GPS used

Comment: You also barely have enough digits in the values to differentiate at the meter-level.

Comment: Antonio , can you give me the link of google which you used ?

Comment: Sure just download Google Earth for your platform